# Automated Desktop Install

Tags: system-installation

Can someone please advise me on the approach to building an offline unattended install for desktop.

I understand the use of seed and kickstart files, however the desktop boots into the live cd rather than an installer like server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the kickstart file into the ISO file and edit the boot menu to load it.

You can do it this way:

1. Mount the original ISO into the /tmp/mountiso directory and copy all the content into the /tmp/custom_iso. This is necessary because as far as I know, it is quite tricky to edit an ISO file directly without extracting.
   (**Note:** if you are installing a desktop version, make sure that you are using the *alternative* version of the ISO)

   ```
   mkdir -p /tmp/mountiso/
   mkdir -p /tmp/custom_iso
   sudo mount -o loop /PATH/TO/THE/UBUNTU/ISO.iso /tmp/mountiso/
   rsync -a /tmp/mountiso/ /tmp/custom_iso/
   echo en > /tmp/custom_iso/isolinux/lang
   ```
2. Edit the file */isolinux/txt.cfg* and replace the default entry with:

   ```
   append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed vga=788 initrd=/install/initrd.gz ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg ---
   ```

   (or just add the *ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg* to the existing line)
3. Create your kickstart file, either with preseed or regular kickstart (or a mixture of them) and place it in */tmp/custom_iso/ks.cfg*
4. Rebuild the ISO with:

   mkisofs -D -r -V "Custom ISO" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o $HOME/my_ubuntu.iso /tmp/custom_iso/

And that's it.

The *$HOME/my_ubuntu.iso* file should boot using your kickstart.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the problem i have is that there is no alternative CD produced anymore.  So the desktop CD is only a live cd not a straight install like the servers CD. so by inserting a seed file i think i am just changing the Live settings not the settings to go on the disk

Comment: It should be possible... Check out this link for Ubuntu 16.04: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/installation-guide/s390x/ch04s03.html